# How to check if a function requires arguments?

Tags: javascript, decorator

How do you check if a function in JavaScript needs arguments to be executed?

```
function functionWithArgs(arg1, arg2) {...}

function functionWithoutArgs() { /* I will return a function here */ }
```

I am checkin if the function has any parameters through ES7 decorators so I don't know the functions name when checking them.

Inside a decorator

```
// If the function has arguments, use descriptor.value without invoking it
if (descriptor.value.HAS_ARGUMENTS) descriptor.value;

// If the function has no arguments, invoke it as it will return a function with arguments
else descriptor.value();
```

Although I am using ES7 decorators, this question should be able to be answered without any knowledge of ES7.

**UPDATE**: I know that I can do something like `if (descriptor.value() === 'undefined')` to determine whether the function returns any value, but that might not always be the case within the returned function.

Comment: Just for reference there's no such thing as ES7 decorators. The ES2016 (ES7) spec is already finalized and decorators are still just a [stage-2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators).

Comment: And you can't know if a function *needs* arguments to run; merely whether it can accept them.

Comment: @DanPrince I failed to mention that I am actually using TypeScript but I did not want to categorize this as a TypeScript question to reach broader audience. And the answer from Nina did well enough for me to use it.

Comment: Gotta be careful with that approach. Not a problem on this question, but there's no guarantee that Typescript decorators work the same way as the ES ones.

Comment: @DanPrince you're right, I just checked and they have only reached the proposal stage by now. I'm currently writing a small framework(actually just sugar on Express.js) to utilise decorators for a more manageable routing structure. It's working extremely well so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of the function.

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters. This number excludes the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/rest_parameters) and only includes parameters before the first one with a default value. By contrast, [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/length) is local to a function and provides the number of arguments actually passed to the function.

```js
function functionWithArgs(arg1, arg2) {}
function functionWithoutArgs() {}

console.log(functionWithArgs.length);    // 2
console.log(functionWithoutArgs.length); // 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me :) Will accept this in 8 minutes. Is this basic stuff that a programmer that has written JavaScript for 3 years should know? D:

Comment: @TânNguyễn I checked this with rest parameters and it indeeds shows 0 as the length. Although using rest parameters will never be the case where I use the decorator on, this might be helpful to others. I'll wait if anyone else has a better answer before accepting this. Soz